# Why am I getting this error? "Cannot insert null into 'VALUE.VALUE_TX'

Tags: sql, oracle

So I've been trying for the last couple days trying to trouble shoot this error. I have a stored procedure that inserts an entry into my staging table. once the staging table has a row inserted, a trigger is fired that loads the data into a couple other tables. My trigger code is below:

```
create or replace TRIGGER xml_load_trigger_value
AFTER INSERT
ON xml_hours_load_2
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (
NEW.processed = 'N'
  ) DECLARE 
Value_ID Number;
pValue_ID Number;
Calculation_ID Number;
pCalculation_ID NUMBER;
Calculation_Value_ID Number;
Hr_Utc Varchar2(4);
p_Entity_Address_ID Varchar2(50);
New_Value_ID Number;
New_Calculation_ID Number;
New_Calculation_Value_ID Number;
New_Value_Tx varchar2(50);
NEW_UTC_Offset varchar2(50);
Survey_Respondent_ID varchar2(50);
NEW_submission_id varchar2(50);


--PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN

Value_ID := value_value_id_seq.NEXTVAL;
New_Value_ID := Value_id;
Calculation_Value_ID :=CALCULATION_VALUE_CALCULATI329.NEXTVAL;
calculation_id := Calculation_Calculation_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;


Insert into Value
(VALUE_ID, PRODUCT_ID, DATA_SOURCE_ID, UNIT_CD, VALUE_TX, UTC_OFFSET,     DATA_DATE, HR_UTC, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_ID)
VALUES
(Value_ID, '109' , '269', 'NA', :NEW.Value_Tx, :NEW.UTC_Offset,     :NEW.Data_Date, :NEW.hr_utc, :NEW.hr, :NEW.hr_num, :NEW.data_code, SYSDATE, '15');
--
Insert into Submission
(SURVEY_RESPONDENT_ID, SUBMISSION_DT, SUBMISSION_TYPE_ID, SUBMISSION_NAME_TX, SUBMISSION_SEQ_NB, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_ID, MODIFY_DT, MODIFY_USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_DT, INACTIVE_DT)
VALUES
('2527451', :NEW.Data_Date, '1', '20190418', '0', sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null);
--
Insert into Submission_Value
(Submission_ID, Value_ID, Form_Field_Id, Create_DT, Create_user_id, Modify_DT, Modify_user_id, Effective_Dt, Inactive_DT)
VALUES
((Select Submission_ID from Submission where Survey_respondent_Id = '2527451' and rownum = 1), Value_Id, '10466', sysdate, '930', null, null, null, null);
END;
```

Comment: Is value.value_tx declared as NOT NULL, and does the staging tables allow nulls? seems the obvious first check given the error message.

Comment: as Andrew said. replace `:NEW.Value_Tx` for a test value to check if you can insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very clear: `:NEW.Value_Tx` is null and your table `Value` has a NOT NULL constraint on the column `VALUE_TX`. So this is Oracle working correctly, enforcing the data integrity rules defined on the table.

So what you need to do is figure out why `:NEW.Value_Tx` is null. It's null because it's null in the row you're inserting into `xml_hours_load_2`. That's what you need to fix.

If it turns out there's a legitimate reason for the null value in the triggering then you need to implement some workaround. Perhaps you need to pass a hard-coded value. Perhaps you need to generate a value (maybe with a sequence). The business rules ought to specify the logic for this.

Comment: I figured it out, someone did a manual insert into my table with all NULL values that I wasn't aware of. once i deleted that row everything was good. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: i see you marked this as a duplicate of another question. this is not a duplicate, these are two different issues that i was having. same table names, but different things i am trying to accomplish. the last one was just loading the data in from a staging table using a stored procedure. Now i am cascading / transferring out the data to other tables in the database.

Comment: The nub of that question is *'i receive a cannot insert NULL into (VALUE."VALUE_TX")' error. '* thrown by a trigger on `xml_hours_load_2` which inserts values into a table called `value`. But please free feel to make a case that these are two different questions.

Comment: You're right my mistake, been asking multiple questions so i forget whether i've asked the questions and then revert to asking when stuck while forgetting i was working on that earlier. sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

`:NEW.Value_Tx` seems to be NULL

and you table Value doesn't allow a NULL value for column `VALUE_TX`

you can do something like that :

```
alter table 
   value
modify 
( 
   value_tx    varchar2(50)
);
```

to disallow the NOT NULL in value_tx column,
but be sure you really want to do that